# Google Maps URLs showing up blank in Xamarin webview on Android

Tags: android, ios, webview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm not trying to use the Google Maps API, just trying to display a standard Google Map URL in a webview inside of my app.

For example - https://www.google.com/maps/place/Disneyland+Park,+1313+Disneyland+Dr,+Anaheim,+CA+92802/@33.812092,-117.918974,17z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x80dcd7d12b3b5e6b:0x2ef62f8418225cfa

When I load that URL, I just get a blank page (works properly on iOS). I've been researching for a couple days now but haven't had any luck in resolving the issue.

One post here on Stackoverflow suggested removing the "s" from "https" and that fixed the problem for them. No such luck for me (seems to always redirect to https now for Google maps).

Another suggested overriding the following method like so...

```
public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading (Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
{
    return false;
}
```

But no luck there either. Also tried handling SSL errors by overriding this method like so....

```
    public override void OnReceivedSslError (Android.Webkit.WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, Android.Net.Http.SslError error)
    {
        handler.Proceed ();
    }
```

But no luck there either, I'm not actually seeing an SSL error so that doesn't surprise me. All other suggestions I've found involved problems with the Google Maps API which I'm not using.

I've also eliminated it being something with my code by creating a sample project in Xamarin and only adding a webview and attempting to load the URL. Still blank.

One workaround I have is that I can detect that a Google Map URL is loading and put that into an iFrame and then that displays properly in the webview. The problem there is that there's not easy way to convert from a standard Google Map URL to the embedded version and the Map displayed is dynamic (set by the user) so ideally they shouldn't have to create the embed link and pull that URL out and set it in our app.

So any suggestions? Something I'm missing? Is this a standard problem on Android? Is it Xamarin doing something?

Any help or new searches or paths I could attempt would be fantastic. Kind of hitting a wall right now and would love some new avenues to try.

Comment: This sounds more like a device specific issue to me as a simple reproduction works just fine on a Nexus 5 device. Have you tried other devices that have Google Maps enabled? (Might need to sign into a google account to view this). Secondly what does your "adb logcat" say with regards to this?

http://imgur.com/ObYYJiL

https://github.com/JonDouglas/xamarin-android-tutorials/tree/master/WebKit/BrowserDemo1

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't considered that it was device specific (although the lack of other people complaining about this issue online should have pointed it that way).

I managed to hunt up a Nexus 7 and sure enough my simple sample app works just fine. Same app on the Samsung devices does not work. Definitely seems to indicate that it's device specific! Feel free to answer the question and I can mark you as correct because I'm pretty sure that's as far as I can take this. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds more like a device specific issue to me as a simple reproduction works just fine on a Nexus 5 device. Have you tried other devices that have Google Maps enabled? (Might need to sign into a google account to view this). Secondly what does your "adb logcat" say with regards to this?

[image: Sample]

https://github.com/JonDouglas/xamarin-android-tutorials/tree/master/WebKit/BrowserDemo1

Comment: Definitely device specific! Sample app works perfectly on the Nexus and fails miserable on the Samsung. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction. Much appreciated!